# Statistical test for group membership

Tags: classification, hypothesis-testing

suppose I have 2 groups - A and B. From those groups we can draw the distribution (median/mean) etc. and do some statistical tests, such as T-test or Wilcoxon test.

Is there any test (similarly, considering group's distribution, to test whether a new sample belongs to which group? This sounds like classification tasks, but is there any statistical tests that I can use for simple-classifier?

Comment: What attributes do you have for the groups? (Yes, this is exactly a classification or, more accurately, a group membership probability problem.)

Comment: @Dave It's a spectra data, i.e. numerical. So, there is no such thing as 'classifier-like statistical test' which can output the probability of group membership?

Comment: You train a model like a logistic regression or a neural network and then you input the new data to make a prediction about the probability of belonging to group A vs group B.